# Книги по asp.net

Tags: asp.net, книги

Здравствуйте. Какие хорошие  книги есть по asp.net для чайников?

Comment: Возможно, вам будут интересны следующие темы:

 - [Учебник по ASP.NET 4.0][1]
 - [Как подготовиться на junior asp.net developer?][2]

P.S. Не забывайте принимать ответы!


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/19977/
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/23031/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

- Дино Эспозито. [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) Базовый курс и Расширенный курс
- Мэтью МакДональд. [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET)